# Circle not rendering to canvas

Tags: webgl

I'm trying to render a circle using WebGL. I only need to translate the circle by a dynamic pixel value, so I used some translation logic from a tutorial converting pixel space to clipspace and put that in the vertex shader. I'm also using the common `TRIANGLE_FAN` technique to make the circle.

I currently can't see anything on the canvas; it renders as a white screen and there is no circle anywhere. I only want the circle to have a radius of 1px.

```js
//shaders
const glsl = (x) => x;

const vertex = glsl`
  attribute vec2 a_position;

  uniform vec2 u_resolution;
  uniform vec2 u_translation;

  void main() {

    //add in the translation
    vec2 position = a_position + u_translation;

    // convert the circle points from pixels to 0.0 to 1.0
    vec2 zeroToOne = a_position / u_resolution;

    // convert from 0->1 to 0->2
    vec2 zeroToTwo = zeroToOne * 2.0;

    // convert from 0->2 to -1->+1 (clipspace)
    vec2 clipSpace = zeroToTwo - 1.0;

    gl_Position = vec4(clipSpace * vec2(1, -1), 0, 1);
  }
`;

const fragment = glsl`
  precision mediump float;

  uniform vec4 u_color;

  void main() {
    gl_FragColor = u_color;
  }
`;

function main() {
  // Get A WebGL context
  var canvas = document.querySelector("#c");
  var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
  if (!gl) {
    return;
  }

  const opacity = 0.5; //opacity will be dynamic
  const color = [0, 0, 0, opacity];
  const translation = [50, 50]; //this translation value with be dynamic but using [50,50] for demo purposes

  // Use our boilerplate utils to compile the shaders and link into a program
  var program = webglUtils.createProgramFromScripts(gl, [vertex, fragment]);

  // look up where the vertex data needs to go.
  var positionAttributeLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");

  // look up uniform locations
  var resolutionUniformLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program,"u_resolution");
  var translationUniformLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_translation");
  var colorUniformLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_color");

  // Create a buffer to put three 2d clip space points in
  var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

  // Bind it to ARRAY_BUFFER (think of it as ARRAY_BUFFER = positionBuffer)
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);

  const positions = [
    0.0, 0.0 //circle center vertex
  ];

  const stops = 100;

  for (i = 0; i < stops; i++){
    positions.push(Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI/stops)); // x coord
    positions.push(Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI/stops)); // y coord
  }

  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(positions), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  //sets canvas width and height to current size of canvas as specified in css
  webglUtils.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);

  // Tell WebGL how to convert from clip space to pixels
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

  // Clear the canvas
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  // Tell it to use our program (pair of shaders)
  gl.useProgram(program);

  // Turn on the attribute
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttributeLocation);

  // Bind the position buffer.
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);

  // Tell the attribute how to get data out of positionBuffer (ARRAY_BUFFER)
  var size = 2; // 2 components per stop
  var type = gl.FLOAT; // the data is 32bit floats
  var normalize = false; // don't normalize the data
  var stride = 0; // 0 = move forward size * sizeof(type) each iteration to get the next position
  var offset = 0; // start at the beginning of the buffer
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(
    positionAttributeLocation,
    size,
    type,
    normalize,
    stride,
    offset
  );

  // set the resolution
  gl.uniform2f(resolutionUniformLocation, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

  //set the translation
  gl.uniform2fv(translationUniformLocation, translation);

  //set the color
  gl.uniform4fv(colorUniformLocation, color);


  // draw
  var primitiveType = gl.TRIANGLE_FAN;
  var offset = 0;
  const count = stops + 1; //adding one for center of circle
  gl.drawArrays(primitiveType, offset, count);
}

main();
```

```html
<script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 problems with the code above

1. It's calling `createProgramFromScripts` instead of `createProgramFromSources`
2. The shader doesn't use `u_translation`

   Here's the first 2 lines

   ```
   //add in the translation
   vec2 position = a_position + u_translation;

   // convert the circle points from pixels to 0.0 to 1.0
   vec2 zeroToOne = a_position / u_resolution;
   ```

   that second line is using `a_position` instead of `position`
3. The fan is missing the last triangle.

   You probably want `<= stops` in your for loop

I'd strongly encourge you to follow the tutorials [there](https://webglfundamentals.org) and get comfortable using matrices. They start with shader code like the code above uses but progress into replacing it with matrices. Even for pixels matrices enable many things that will be hard without.